# change CTreeCtrl Item image

Tags: c++, mfc

Help me please to change `CTreeCtrl` image on item click event.

I add the image to the imagelist like this:

```
HICON hChecked, hUnChecked;

// Set up the image list.
m_imglist.Create(21, 21, ILC_COLOR32,1, 1);
 
hChecked = reinterpret_cast<HICON>(
        ::LoadImage(AfxGetResourceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_Check_ICO),
            IMAGE_ICON, 21, 21, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR));
 
hUnChecked = reinterpret_cast<HICON>(
        ::LoadImage(AfxGetResourceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_UnCheck_ICO),
            IMAGE_ICON, 21, 21, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR));
    
m_imglist.Add(hUnChecked);
m_imglist.Add(hChecked);
    
m_tree.SetImageList(&m_imglist, TVIF_IMAGE);
```

Then I am trying to change the image like this, but it doesn't work:

```
m_tree.SetItem(this->GetRootItem(), TVIF_IMAGE, NULL, 2,2,0,0,0);
```

Help me please to find a solution. Finally i need to have a custom checkbox (checked.ico and unchecked.ico) to be loaded on item click event. thank you!!!

Comment: Why aren't you using the TVS_CHECKBOXES [tree-view control style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Controls/tree-view-control-window-styles)?

Comment: I need a custom look for checkboxes, because i am not using them

Comment: Why not replace the standard bitmaps then instead of rolling your own?

Comment: How to do it? What do you mean by replacing of standart bitmaps?

Comment: The documentation I linked to in my first comments explains how a tree-view control with the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` works, and how the state image lists relates to the display of checkboxes.